# app for token android.os.BinderProxy@be12cf1 has too many windows 20

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
Unable to add window -- app for token android.os.BinderProxy@be12cf1 has too many windows 20
```

I am getting this crash in my crashlytics a lot. I cannot share the code but can anyone help in giving a code snippet on what causes this crash?

p.s: cannot find this error in android source code.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- app for token android.os.BinderProxy@7fd051f has too many windows 20
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:993)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:408)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:372)
   at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:529)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2731)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:365)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1206)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2595)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:258)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:550)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
   at com.carthero.driver.views.activities.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:101)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1479)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7891)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3545)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2242)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7789)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown from within the Android Framework code, inside your app process. The stacktrace points to ViewRootImpl.setView, and [in that file](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java;l=1068-1108;drc=344f4d71075b98ee15696ef81484f03bab1848cb) we can find several WindowManager$BadTokenException being thrown with a message that's somewhat similar, but not the exact same.

```java
switch (res) {
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_BAD_APP_TOKEN:
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_BAD_SUBWINDOW_TOKEN:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException(
                "Unable to add window -- token " + attrs.token
                + " is not valid; is your activity running?");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_NOT_APP_TOKEN:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException(
                "Unable to add window -- token " + attrs.token
                + " is not for an application");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_APP_EXITING:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException(
                "Unable to add window -- app for token " + attrs.token
                + " is exiting");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_DUPLICATE_ADD:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException(
                "Unable to add window -- window " + mWindow
                + " has already been added");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_STARTING_NOT_NEEDED:
        // Silently ignore -- we would have just removed it
        // right away, anyway.
        return;
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_MULTIPLE_SINGLETON:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException("Unable to add window "
                + mWindow + " -- another window of type "
                + mWindowAttributes.type + " already exists");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_PERMISSION_DENIED:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException("Unable to add window "
                + mWindow + " -- permission denied for window type "
                + mWindowAttributes.type);
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_INVALID_DISPLAY:
        throw new WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException("Unable to add window "
                + mWindow + " -- the specified display can not be found");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_INVALID_TYPE:
        throw new WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException("Unable to add window "
                + mWindow + " -- the specified window type "
                + mWindowAttributes.type + " is not valid");
    case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_INVALID_USER:
        throw new WindowManager.BadTokenException("Unable to add Window "
                + mWindow + " -- requested userId is not valid");
}
```

So you probably are facing a source change made by a specific manufacturer, because their device cannot handle that many windows from a single app.

The error message suggests that your app already has 20 windows added, which seems like a lot, but might make sense with a deep activity stack (since every activity = 1 window).

You could try to ship with [square/curtains](https://github.com/square/curtains) to keep track of which windows are being added and figure out where the high number comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer py, i'll try out that curtains but is there any way that we can reproduce this ? may be run an infinte loop keep adding windows and it should break in sometime. vivo device throwed this crash the most but we never saw this crash in my staging crashlytics and happening only in prod.